# Issue in data insertion mongodb error

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongo java driver and doing collection.insert().
Exception is as below:

```
com.mongodb.WriteConcernException: Write failed with error code 8 and error message 'assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/extent.h:81'
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.convertBulkWriteException(BaseWriteOperation.java:239)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.access$300(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:146)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation$1.call(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:230)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:133)
    at com.mongodb.operation.BaseWriteOperation.execute(BaseWriteOperation.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:782)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:765)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:333)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:328)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:319)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:192)
```

Similar to this i get error if i import a new collection:
query :

```
mongoimport --db testdb --collection test --file test.json

2016-07-07T18:31:13.599+0000    error inserting documents: assertion src/mongo/db/storage/mmap_v1/extent.h:81
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error means the data files Mongodb are corrupted.

You should run mongod

mongod --repair

Comment: Did try. Dint work. We backed up entire data and had to install new instance and restore data again.